# Spring Cloud Stream/Function: Kotlin lambdas without the use of Java Function/BiFunction

Tags: kotlin, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a Kafka stream processing application written using Spring Boot, using `spring-cloud-function` and `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams`. The method which processes a couple of streams is annotated with `@Bean`, so that it should be picked up by `spring-cloud-function` (rather than using `@StreamListener`). When this method returns a `BiFunction` it works. But when I try it as a plain Kotlin lambda it's not picked up by Spring Boot: the app starts then immediately ends as it finds no functions to run.

From what I can see in [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_kotlin_lambda_support), this should work.

Here's the declaration that *does* work:

```
@Bean
fun process():
        BiFunction<KStream<String, Foo>, GlobalKTable<String, Bar>, KStream<String, Baz>> =
    BiFunction { foo, bar ->
        ...
```

And here's the declaration that does *not* work:

```
@Bean
fun process():
        (foo: KStream<String, Foo>, bar: GlobalKTable<String, Bar>) -> KStream<String, Baz> = 
    { foo, bar ->
            ...
```

(The content of the method is the same in both cases.)

As per the documentation, I have added the `spring-cloud-function-kotlin` module to the classpath by adding this to `build.gradle.kts`:

```
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-function-kotlin")
```

The version of Spring Cloud Stream is `Hoxton.RC1`.

Is there anything else I need to do to get the function picked up?  Or do I need to use `BiFunction` in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (in 3.0), the Kafka Streams binding functional support requires `java.util.function` types. It does not work with standard functions in Kotlin yet (or we haven't validated anything in that regard). We are planning to look into this as a 3.1 feature. If you don't mind, could you create a new issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues)?

Comment: Thanks Soby, that explains it. Have logged an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/795